# In a cmake.txt file, how can I add a .cpp source file to a Visual Studio project but not have it compile?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

How do I add .cpp files to a project and have them visible in the project but not included in the compile?  Basically I want the "Excluded From Build" flag to be set to "Yes".  I want to do this for C++ Unity style builds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it looks like I need to do something like this:

```
# Exclude all translation units from compilation
set_source_files_properties(${files} PROPERTIES HEADER_FILE_ONLY true)
```

My reference:

http://cheind.wordpress.com/2009/12/10/reducing-compilation-time-unity-builds/

Answer (score 0):

You could also set the language of the file to something undefined:

```
set_source_files_properties(${files} PROPERTIES LANGUAGE xxx)
```